# If I know where the information I want is on a site, how can I scrape it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath, web-scraping

I have a problem, I know what information I want to scrape of a website and I also know where the information is at. I know in what class it's in and also the xpath.

The problem I'm having is that no matter what I try, it seems like I can't scrape the content.

This is my scrape function:

```js
function scrape(doc, url) {
  var itemType = detectWeb(doc, doc.location.href);

  var keywords = new Array();
  var keywordText = doc.evaluate('//div[span="Index Terms:"]/div', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
  if (keywordText) keywords = (Zotero.Utilities.trimInternal(keywordText.textContent.toLowerCase())).split(",");
  var attachments = new Array();
  var notes = new Array();
  attachments.push({
    document: doc,
    mimeType: "text/html",
    title: "IEEE Computer Snapshot"
  });

  var htmls = doc.evaluate('//img[@src="/plugins/images/digitalLibrary/dl_html_icon.gif"]/ancestor::a', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var htmlDoc;

  //TESTING
  //var affiliation = doc.getElementsByTagName('meta')[property='citation_author_institution'].content; 
  //var affiliations = [];  

  var abstracts;


  if (htmlDoc = htmls.iterateNext()) {
    //var urlField = htmlDoc.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value;
    var urlField = htmlDoc.href;
    urlField = urlField.substr(urlField.indexOf('"') + 1);
    urlField = urlField.substr(0, urlField.indexOf('"'));
    if (urlField.indexOf("?") > -1) {
      urlField += '&' + templte;
    } else {
      urlField += '?' + templte;
    }
    urlField = "http://www2.computer.org" + urlField;
    var mimeTypeField = "text/html";
    var titleField = "IEEE Computer Full Text Snapshot";
    var attachment = {
      url: urlField,
      mimeType: mimeTypeField,
      title: titleField
    };
    attachments.push(attachment);
  }

  var pdfurl = ZU.xpathText(doc, '//div[@class="abs-pdf"]/a/@href')
  if (pdfurl) {
    var mimeTypeField = "application/pdf";
    var titleField = "IEEE Computer Full Text PDF";
    var attachment = {
      url: pdfurl,
      mimeType: mimeTypeField,
      title: titleField
    };
    attachments.push(attachment);
  } else {
    notes.push({
      note: "Complete PDF document was either not available or accessible. Please make sure you're logged in to the digital library to retrieve the complete PDF document."
    });
  }

  var bibtex = doc.evaluate('//div[@id="bibText-content"]', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
  var bibtexlink = ZU.xpathText(doc, '//li/a[contains(text(), "BibTex") and contains(@href, ".bib")]/@href')
  if (bibtex) {
    bibtex = bibtex.textContent;
    //bibtex = bibtex.substring(bibtex.indexOf("document.write('")+16,bibtex.indexOf("');Popup.document.close();"));
    //workaround as bibtex translator obviously needs a whitespace following the first curly brace
    bibtex = Zotero.Utilities.cleanTags(bibtex);
    bibtex = Zotero.Utilities.trimInternal(bibtex);
    var translator = Zotero.loadTranslator("import");
    translator.setTranslator("9cb70025-a888-4a29-a210-93ec52da40d4");
    translator.setString(bibtex);
    translator.setHandler("itemDone", function(obj, item) {
      if (item.url) { // add http to url
        item.url = "http://" + item.url;
      }
      if (itemType) item.itemType = itemType;
      item.attachments = attachments;
      if (keywords) item.tags = keywords;
      if (notes) item.notes = notes;
      if (item.DOI) item.DOI = item.DOI.replace(/^.*?10\./, "10.");

      //Affiliations
      /*if (affiliation)
                {
                    for (i=0; i<affiliations.length; i++)
                    {
                        affiliation.push(affiliations[i].textContent)
                    }

                    item.extra = affiliation.join("; ");
                }*/

      if (abstracts) {
        item.abstractNote = abstracts;
      }

      item.complete();
    });
    translator.translate();

  } else if (bibtexlink) {
    ZU.doGet(bibtexlink, function(text) {
      var translator = Zotero.loadTranslator("import");
      translator.setTranslator("9cb70025-a888-4a29-a210-93ec52da40d4");
      translator.setString(text);
      translator.setHandler("itemDone", function(obj, item) {
        if (item.url) { // add http to url
          item.url = "http://" + item.url;
        }
        if (itemType) item.itemType = itemType;
        item.attachments = attachments;

        if (keywords) item.tags = keywords;
        if (notes) item.notes = notes;
        if (item.DOI) item.DOI = item.DOI.replace(/^.*?10\./, "10.");

        //Affiliations
        /*if (affiliation)
                    {
                        for (i=0; i<affiliations.length; i++)
                        {
                            affiliation.push(affiliations[i].textContent)
                        }

                        item.extra = affiliation.join("; ");
                    }*/

        //Abstract
        if (abstracts) {
          item.abstractNote = abstracts;
        }

        item.complete();
      });
      translator.translate();
    })
  } else {
    throw "No BibTeX found!";
  }
}
```

It's the variable called abstracts that I wanna fill with the abstract from this website.

[ieee article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1701938)

I used Firebug to locate where this information was stored and found it in the `class="article"` in the `div="tabs-main"`.

It looks something like this:

```
<div id="tabs-main">
            <!-- place holder -->
<div class="tab-content" id="articleDetails" role="main" data-section="articleDetails.ajax" 
 >
<div class="article-blk">



<div class="article">
  (I want this)-->  <p>Distributed database systems (DDBS) have received considerable attention in recent years. Being a relatively young research field, there are still many problems associated with DDB systems that need solution. Concurrency control is one of these problems and, probably, the most extensively studied. However, most of the work has concentrated on the development of alternative solutions and the field seems to be ready for some comparative analysis work. This paper reports the results of a performance evaluation study on distributed database concurrency control algorithms. The research has resulted in the development of a formalism, based on Petri nets, for modeling and analysis purposes. The formalism, called the Extended Place/Transition Nets (EPTN), is both descriptively powerful in that it can be used to model various algorithms precisely and succinctly and to communicate them in a clear manner, while at the same time lending itself to be used as a performance evaluation tool. An EPTN simulator is implemented and various algorithms are studied using this tool. This paper describes both the formalism and the performance results that have been obtained.</p>
            </div>
```

And in Firebug I also get the XPath which is:
`/html/body/div[2]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]`

But I don't know how I can get this content. I have tried with 
`var abstracts = doc.querySelector(".article").innerHTML;`

I have tried with `doc.getElementByClassName()`.

But I can never get the content, var is always null.
Someone out there have an idea?

Comment: How are you accessing the doc? If it's cross-origin, that's your problem, the SOP blocks JavaScript code running in a page from Origin A from accessing the content of a page in Origin B (even if it's got a reference to that document, such as in the case of frames).

Comment: Hmm, not really sure what you mean. How can I se if I have cross-origin then?

Comment: I'm using a DOI to access the document if that's what you mean?
I get the DOI from a db I have locally and use that to redirect me to the site with the wanted info

Comment: And most importanly, how can I go around this problem or fix it?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to write a "translator" for Zotero browser extension? In that case you would not be affected by the cross-origin issue. But you would probably get more support on Zotero forum, or at least here by properly stating that your code is for an extension.

Comment: That totally right Ghybs, it is a Zotero extension. Didn't realise that it matter so I'm sorry for that. Was just asking here also since I haven't got any response from Zotero forum yet.

Do you have any reading tips or any other tip for me maybe?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Zotero. Unfortunately your need is very specific, and given the low number of questions relative to Zotero on StackOverflow (91!), you would better wait for help from their forum, if you cannot find information in already published questions or with Google. Good luck!